# How to find basis and dimensions of ColA, RowA and NulA^T from NulA?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A 3x3 symmetric matrix has a null space of dimension one
containing the vector (1,1,1). Find bases and dimensions
of the column space, row space, and left null space.

I know that, since the matrix is 3x3 and the dimension of the null space is one, the dimension of the column space would be 2. I also know that since the matrix is symmetric, the left null space would be the same as the column space. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to find a basis without having the actual matrix.

Comment: It's the dimension of the *column* space that would be equal to $2$, from the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Hint: The null space of any matrix is the orthogonal complement of its row space, and then use symmetry.